# Improving the accuracy on Haar Training with OpenCV binary

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I've been using Haar Cascades and LBP cascades trained with the `opencv_traincascade` tool which is brilliant.

I'd like to hear some purposes about how to generate a bigger database which in fact improves the accuracy. What I mean is: let's imagine we've got 2,000 positive images and 10,000 negative images. For CNN (Convolutional Neural Networks) I've rotated, translated and scaled pictures in order to multiplicate those 2,000 into a 8,000 positive samples which really improves the results, but I don't really have clear what I could do for Cascade Training.

My purposes are:

1. Generate a part of the positive set with noise. For instance:
   [image]
2. Generate a part of the positive set with highlights or blenders.

Have you used anything else or tried something which could improve the accuracy?

Thank you in advance.

Rafael.